# Camel Zip with multiple entries

Tags: apache-camel

I have a message that comes in via a queue. I want to send that message off to a signing service.  This service returns a signature.  I then want to put the original message and the signature message into a Zip file as two seperate Zip entries.  I want to asked for the world on a stick and do this as a blueprint, and entirely via XML with no compiled java code (other than my signing microservice which is already built and running in our infrastructure).

Ideas?

Looking at the docs and playing around with it I think I can...maybe.

It seems the default aggregators might not do quite what I need for this usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.  Below is a PoC:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=1s").to("direct:start");
            from("direct:start").setBody().simple("hello").multicast(new ZipAggregationStrategy(true, true)).to("direct:a", "direct:b").end().to("file://target?fileName=any.zip");
            from("direct:a").setHeader("CamelFileName").simple("data.txt").to("log:mylog");
            from("direct:b").setHeader("CamelFileName").simple("signature.txt").to("http://mysignatureservice");
        }
    });
```